# How can i display massages based on the user who sent and received the message

Tags: javascript, dom

I don't know what's wrong with my code am not getting the intended output. Anybody to lend a helping hand and I'll really appreciate it.

If append the row class inside the for loop am getting all the messages but you can't differentiate who sent and who received and when I append the class outside the for loop am only getting one message.

```js
xhr.onload = function () {
  var messages = [
    { id: 36, message: "hay here", username: null, senderId: 1, receiverId: 9 },
    { id: 38, message: "hay there again", username: null, senderId: 1, receiverId: 9 },
    { id: 37, message: "yes  hay", username: null, senderId: 9, receiverId: 1 },
  ];
  
  var rowClass = "";

  for (var message = 0; message < messages.length; message++) {
    if (messages[message].senderId === messages[message].senderId) {
      rowClass =
        '<div style="text-align:right">' +
        '<p style="background-color:lightblue">' +
        mymessages[message].message +
        "</p>" +
        "<div>";
    } else {
      rowClass =
        '<div style="text-align:left">' + '<p style="background-color:green">';
      messages[message].message;
      "</p>" + "<div>";
    }
  }
  $(".message").append(rowClass);
};
```

Comment: Using `rowClass=` in the loop will overwrite all but the last iteration. You want `rowClass +=` in order to add to existing string. Or more verbose `rowClass = rowClass + '<div...`

Comment: but again all the messages are being displayed and i cant differenciate who is the sender and receiver and does my code look correct

Comment: Because the `if()` is always true. It's essentially the same as doing `if( 1===1)`.

Comment: @charlietfl this is the object from the rest endpoitn   var messages=[
  { id: 36, message: "hay here", username: null, senderId: 1, receiverId: 9 },
  { id: 38, message: "hay there again", username: null, senderId: 1, receiverId: 9 },
  { id: 37, message: "yes  hay", username: null, senderId: 9, receiverId: 1 },
], i want to display to the right or left based on who sent and who recived.

Comment: I think what is missing is a variable that identifies the id of the current user of that page

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the current user's id is same as that of the message, for example:

```js
const currentUserId = 9;

var messages = [
  { id: 36, message: "hay here", username: null, senderId: 1, receiverId: 9 },
  { id: 38, message: "hay there again", username: null, senderId: 1, receiverId: 9 },
  { id: 37, message: "yes  hay", username: null, senderId: 9, receiverId: 1 },
];

var rowClass = "";

for (var message = 0; message < messages.length; message++) {
  if (messages[message].senderId === currentUserId) {
    rowClass +=
      '<div style="text-align:right">' +
      '<p style="background-color:lightblue">' +
      messages[message].message +
      "</p>" +
      "<div>";
  } else {
    rowClass +=
      '<div style="text-align:left">' +
      '<p style="background-color:green">' +
      messages[message].message +
      "</p>" +
      "<div>";
  }
}

$(".message").append(rowClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message"></div>
```

Comment: Cheers bro uve helped me figure out.But this means I have to make another xhr request  to get the id of the current User?

Comment: @TopKalu I don't think you have to make a new request, you can save the user id and other information in Local Storage or application state etc, and then just get the user id from there.